# How to scroll page to a custom location

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking to scroll the page to a particular location.Something like this:

```
function scrollTo(y){
  document.body. some-property = y;
}
```

I am looking to solve this without using any libraries.

I know scrollTop works in some browsers but I tried it if FF 3.6 and IE 8 and it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to complete that function ?

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer, you can reverse engineer http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html to use the standard DOM API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.scrollTo).

```
function scrollTo(y){
    window.scrollTo(0, y);
}
```